# Get current object on has_many side when saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an Event that has many Equipments. I want to validate the Equipment model. How can I access the equipment's event that I am currently saving? I need that to get the date when the equipment will be used(date is known from Event model). Here is the code:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :equipment_events, class_name: EquipmentEvent
    has_many :equipment, through: :equipment_events
end

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :equipment_events
    has_many :events, through: :equipment_events

    validate :equipment_already_used

  def equipment_already_used
     date = # <== HERE I need the date from this equipment's event that I am saving
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the validation from Equipment to EquipmentEvent, since Equipment and Event are independent entities.

```
class EquipmentEvent < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :equipment
  belongs_to :event

  validate :equipment_already_used

  def equipment_already_used
    event.date # <== HERE
  end

end
```